over 2 weeks with editor after major revision
I would like to know if it is normal 2 weeks after major revision my paper is still with editor and he doesn't send it to reviewers. I'm concerned that maybe my revision wasn't satisfactory.

No, do not conclude "revision wasn't satisfactory".  Probably the editor is busy with start-of-term activities at his "real" job.

Please see the duplicate. Briefly: If the editor concluded that your revision wasn’t satisfactory, you would already know.
